# Where I should ask questions about English naming conventions in programming?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a lot of questions about variables and functions naming. Just English proficiency is not enough to answer these questions because variables naming has it's own slang and also irregular grammar. So it will be down-voted in Stack Overflow about English language.

However, questions like "'targetFileAbsolutePath' and 'absolutePathOfTargetFile' - what is more correct?" most likely will be downvoted on programming Stack Overflow, too.

What should I do?

Comment: It probably would be closed as opinion-based anywhere, as you're effectively asking which naming convention is better, and that can be a very opinionated topic.

Comment: There is a naming-conventions tag on StackOverflow; looking at which questions are closed versus not may help you formulate your question in an answerable, non-opinion-based way (though I suspect that may not be possible).

Comment: Dear everyone, thank you for the comments. Does some alternative forums exist where asking of above questions is being welcome?

Comment: The example question will be downvoted everywhere because it is **opinion-based**. There is no correct answer.

Comment: its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has". See for example *["Weird Al" Yankovic - Word Crimes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc&t=1m20s)* and *[How to Use Its and It's](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s)*. You can edit your question.

Comment: @OrangeDog, even it's opinion based, does the asking like "which patterns of boolean variable naming are exists?" requires objective answer!